# Using optional arguments from command line within the system function in perl

Tags: perl, command-line, system

I am generalizing a pre-existing perl script... i.e.  making it work on numerous instances simultaneously. Basically it is a parameter scan feature of a modelling script. The scan does a single parameter and I want it to do them all. The pre-existing script (called scan_var.pl from bionetgen if your interested) has a bunch of arguments - some of them optional.

The following is successful in implementing  the parameter scan with the default settings

```
#execute the parameter scan with each variable individually

foreach $var_name (@var_names){

    my $param = shift @var_names;
    system ("perl", $scan_var_location, $model, $param, $min_value, $max_value, $NPTS);
}
```

But now I want to use the `GetOpt::Long` module to parse in the optional arguments. My code so far is:

```
# some default parameters
my $log     = 0;
my $t_end   = 20;
my $n_steps = 1;
my $steady_state = 0;
my $method = "\"ode\"";
my $verbose = 0;
my $prefix;

my $options = GetOptions ( 
                           'verbose'      => \$verbose, #boolean
                           'log'          => \$log, #boolean
                           'n_steps:i'    => \$n_steps, #integer
                           'steady_state' => \$steady_state, #boolean
                           'method:s'     => \$method, #string
                           't_end:i'      => \$t_end, #integer
                           'prefix:s'     => \$prefix string
                         );

#execute the parameter scan with each variable individually

foreach $var_name (@var_names){ #iterates through a list stored in $var_names(not shown for concise-ness)

    my $param = shift @var_names;

    system ("perl", $scan_var_location, #required value, directory
                    $options, #optional command line arguments - corresponds to the list above
                    $model, #required command line value (directory)
                    $param, #list iterated over
                    $min_value, #requierd integer
                    $max_value, #required integer
                    $NPTS #required integer
           );
}
```

This however is somehow incorrect. Does anybody have any suggestions for corrections?

Cheers

Comment: *Always* `use strict; use warnings;`! And please describe your problem in more detail.

Comment: Your code would be much more readable and easier to debug if you put each parameter-pair for `GetOptions` on a separate line. As it stands you have `'n_steps:i' => \ \$n_steps,` and the additional backslash is superfluous.

Comment: Biffen - The use strict and warnings are on, this is only the bottom of my script as it is too long to ask people to read it all, (but thanks for the advice anyway). As for more detail - I've attempted to  make it so if I use the optional arguments my new script will automatically use them within the system function. I guess the problem is that some are boolean whereas others have numeric values.

Answer (score 1):

[`GetOptions()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt%3a%3aLong#Storing-options-values-in-a-hash) supports the storage of values in a hash. This allows you to reduce variable clutter:

```
use Getopt::Long;

my %options;
GetOptions( \%options,
                       'verbose',
                           'log',
                     'n_steps:i',
                  'steady_state',
                      'method:s',
                       't_end:i',
                      'prefix:s',
          );

my $stringified_options = join ' ', map "-$_ $options{$_}", keys %options;

foreach my $var_name ( @var_name ) {

    system ("perl", $scan_var_location,
                    $stringified_options,
                    $model,
                    $param, 
                    $min_value,
                    $max_value,
                    $NPTS
           );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you probably don't want to use the **return value** of `GetOptions` in your `system` call.  `$options` has the return value:

> GetOptions returns true to indicate success. It returns false when the
>   function detected one or more errors during option parsing.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a tighter version of your code:

```
GetOptions ( 
    'verbose'      => \(my $verbose = 0),        #boolean
    'log'          => \(my $log     = 0),        #boolean
    'n_steps:i'    => \(my $n_steps = 1),        #integer
    'steady_state' => \(my $steady_state = 0),   #boolean
    'method:s'     => \(my $method = q{"ode"}),  #string
    't_end:i'      => \(my $t_end   = 20),       #integer
    'prefix:s'     => \my $prefix,               #string
);

#execute the parameter scan with each variable individually

#iterates through a list stored in $var_names(not shown for concise-ness)
foreach $var_name (@var_names) { 
    system("perl", 
        $scan_var_location,   #required value, directory
        $model,               #required command line value (directory)
        $var_name,            #list iterated over
        $min_value,           #requierd integer
        $max_value,           #required integer
        $NPTS,                #required integer
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks - makes sense... I was wandering, what is the backslash for before the bracket in this context? I used them just because I saw how it was done in other examples but I didn't understand why. It can't be an escape character, can it?

Comment: The backslash is to pass a reference to the scalars to `GetOptions`.  That is the mechanism that the `GetOptions` function uses to set values in lexical variables.